# Is it possible to perform a GGE analysis with metan package using more variables?

Tags: r

I am  using in R a dataset which include several wheat genotypes in 2 and 3 replications evaluated in three different location along 3/4 years for several triats such us grain yield (GY), heading day (HD), plant heigth (PH) and protein content (PROT).

I am performing this code in order to get and plot the interaction between environments and genotypes for grain yield (GY) trait. I wonder if it possible to add also the other variables, not only GY.

```
gge_model <- gge(x, ENV, CODE, GY, svp = "symmetrical")
a <- plot(gge_model, type = 3,
          max_overlaps = 5)
```

Typing this code, it doesn't work, and I would like to know if there is something similar to get it.

```
gge_model <- gge(x, LOC, CODE, PROT, GY, HD, svp = "symmetrical")
```

Given error:

```
Error in centering %in% c("none", "environment", "global", "double") : 
  object 'GY' not found
```

Comment: What does `names(x)` return? The error is indicating that you are calling a variable name that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Phil! Thank you very much for your interest! I have discovered where i was failing. I wasn't using the right comand to include more variables in the analysis.